# aws sqs - does message is considered as inflight message if sqs worker changed the message visibility timeout but does not delete it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

sqs has inflight message limit of 120000. If sqs worker/consumer receives the message and change the visibility timeout of message but don't delete it. Will it be still counted as inflight message after changing visibility timeout?

If visibilityTimeout of message is changed using receiptHandle is it possible to delete the sqs message using same receiptHandle?

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you have lots of questions with answers, yet only two has ever been accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it also reduced duplicates and makes your questions more likely to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it be still counted as inflight message after changing visibility timeout?

Yes, because it has been received and not yet deleted or it has timeout.

> is it possible to delete the sqs message using same receiptHandle?

Yes.

Its a **common pattern** to keep extending the visibility timeout of messages while you are processing them and you don't know up-front how much time you need for that.